# How do I 'findViewById' in fragment with RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, findviewbyid

I have a ConstraintLayout inside RecyclerView which lives in a fragment. I want to change the dimensions of the ConstraintLayout (based on screen resolution) but can't seem to find the right way of getting the ConstraintLayout in code.

I've tried:

view!!.findViewById(R.id.postConstraint)

activity!!.findViewById(R.id.postConstraint)

Both of which return null.

My Fragment

```
package no.alacho.pgr202_positivity

import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Point
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Display
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.single_post_item.*

class Posts : Fragment() {

  private lateinit var layoutManager: GridLayoutManager
  private lateinit var adapter: PostAdapter
  private lateinit var display: Display
  private lateinit var size: Point

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    display = activity!!.windowManager.defaultDisplay
    size = Point()
    display.getSize(size)
  }

  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
  }

  override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2)
    postRecycler.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2)
    adapter = PostAdapter()
    postRecycler.adapter = adapter

    //view!!.findViewById<Button>(R.id.hurraButton).text =  "Something"

    view!!.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.postConstraint).minWidth = 100
    activity!!.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.postConstraint).minWidth = 100
  }
}
```

And my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="150dp"
        android:minWidth="150dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF0000"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:id="@+id/postConstraint">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hurraButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hallo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Don't try to alter the enclosing host Activity views from a fragment. It is not safe

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: `activity.findViewById` <-- don't do that, like, ever

Answer (score 1):

Try to initalize it in onCreateView.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    var rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.YourRecyclerViewId)
    return rootView
 }
```

Make the variable global to use it in oder functions. I hope this helps.

Comment: It found the view now, that's awesome! Thank you! :D

Comment: Your welcome, please mark as aceptet solution if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the Adapter and the ViewHolder of the RecyclerView, try doing this:

```
class Posts : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var adapter: MyAdapter

    ...

    class MyAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {


        ...

        override fun onBindViewHolder (viewHolder: MyViewHolder, pos: Int) {
            viewHolder.bind()
        }

    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val constraintLayout = itemView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.postConstraint)

        fun bind() {
            constraintLayout.minWidth = 100  //You should use LayoutParams to modify View bounds
        }
    }
}
```

If you have problem in implementing your custom Adapter and ViewHolder leave a comment and I'll implement that.

Comment: The red area doesn't belong to the RecyclerView, so you should access it in the OnCreateView of your Posts class with a findViewById on the fragment content view, or simply by setting an OnClickListener on your inflated view (always in onCreateView)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I actually deleted my comment because I realised that it wasn't related to the original question, but thank you!

Comment: If my answer is right, please consider to check it as correct, to help other users finding easily the correct solution